# Remove the Paragraph tags

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a lot of Word docs that have all kinds of fluff in them that need to be removed.
The files contain scripts for voiceovers and subtitles.
I currently go through them with a bunch of "find and replace" in Word:

```
\<Slide*\> 
\[?lick\]
\(?lick\)
```

This gets rid of 98% of the useless tags, however, I'm stuck with tons of paragraphs.
Sometimes there are 2 empty ones behind/below each other, sometimes there's 6 or even more.

I was trying my luck with VBA macros to try and look for any paragraph tag that was followed by another paragraph tag and then remove it, but it not working.
I tried it in find and replace as well, but it will reduce 2 tags to 1 tag.
So, if I (for instance) have 8, I still end up with 4, which means I have to do it multiple times.
After getting fed up with it I just removed them by hand but it keeps gnawing at me.
Is there someone out there that can help me??

Comment: No VBA required. See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/174374-post2.html Also: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm and https://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

Comment: Perfect! I'll try to incorporate the other "clean up" steps...

Comment: I combined some macro/vba scipts. 
First it now displays an input box where you can input your search string (coma separated), then your replace string (again, coma separated). After that ran, it goes through the document and removes all the "extra paragraphs".
Thanks for helping me getting back on track again!